# c# Get Process ID from Window Title

Tags: c#, forms

**How do i get Process id from window title?** I need to get pid from window title and after its found i need to check if the process with that pid is running and if its not running i pause the background worker by changing the _state.wait.

**This is what i have tried:**

```
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 1;
            List<string> proctxt = new List<string>();

            while (true)
            {
                _state.Wait();


                if (i == 1)
                {
                    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                    foreach (Process Proc in processlist)
                    {
                        string text = Proc.MainWindowTitle + " = " + Proc.Id.ToString();
                        proctxt.Add(text);
                    }
                }

                if ( i == 2)
                {
                    int index = proctxt.FindIndex(a => a.Contains("Bot")) + 1;
                    string pid = proctxt[index];
                }


                if (proctxt.Contains("Bot") && i == 1)
                {
                    i++;
                }


                if (!proctxt.Contains("Bot") && i == 2)
                {
                    i--;
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { button8.Enabled = true; }));
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { button3.Enabled = false; }));
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { button4.Enabled = false; }));
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { _state.Paused = true; }));
                }
                proctxt.Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is how i got Process ID from Window Title:**

```
private void function1()
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("my process");

            string title = "title";
            string procID;
            
            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (String.Equals(process.MainWindowTitle, title))
                {
                    procID = process.Id.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("This is the process ID: " + process.Id);
                    MessageBox.Show(procID);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Window not found");
                }                
            }
        }
```